# Icons not visible on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I created icon usin this code

```
.iconhouse{
  content:url('images/ico/home.png');
  float:left;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:1px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

And used this icon like this

```
<a href="#" class=""><span class="iconhouse"></span>Sample text</a>
```

Safari and Chrome works fine and I get my icon, but Firefox seems to miss it. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using an inspector to see if the span is collapsing for some reason?

Comment: Span is there. <span class="iconhouse"></span>

Comment: Maybe I should change the motheod of how I get the icon there? I saw this kind of thing while ago <span class="iconhouse">::before</span>

Comment: Span is there but is it visible on the page? Like is the anchor hiding it?

Comment: It takes that 15px space, So it is visible.

Comment: Is it live anywhere? If you can replicate it on jsfiddle i can take a look

Comment: Ok. I just uploaded my site. Take a look at www.ekra.lv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.iconhouse {
   content:url('images/ico/home.png');
   float:left;
   display: block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   padding-right:10px;
   padding-top:1px;
   color:#fff;
}
}
```

This should target Firefox only. Let us know how you get on :)

Comment: No luck with this one. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the anchor tag a width and height if you are only using the anchor tag for an image (anchor without text/only the image)

```
.divclass a.iconhouse {
    content:url('images/ico/home.png');
    float:left;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:1px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Didint help either. I have this item as a list item for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me. Adding this snippet to my .htaccessfile

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I find this to be especially the case when I transfer sites from my dev server to a new server, or where the icons are being served from a different IP address/URL.